# Access the type a subtype of a generic class ?

Tags: swift, swift3

Is there a way in Swift to access the class specified to a generic class ?

For example :

```
class MyClass<T> {} 
var myVar:MyClass<SomeOtherClass>
```

I would like to access SomeOtherClass when I have a MyClass object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *create* a way to access that generic parameter:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    static var RelatedType: Any.Type { return T.self }
}

var myVar = MyClass<String>()
print(type(of: myVar).RelatedType) //prints "String"
```